# How to create a ssl serversocket using netty library

Tags: java, ssl, netty, serversocket

We have the following code to create a ssl serversocket using `javax.net.ssl`:

```
private final ServerSocket serverSocket;
private final SslFactory sslFactory;
...
SSLContext sslContext = this.sslFactory.sslContext();
this.serverSocket = sslContext.getServerSocketFactory().createServerSocket(0);
```

We need to change this code in order to *use the netty ssl client lib instead*. Could anyone tell how do we create a serversocket using netty lib, assume that we have an `io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext` object. I have tried to search online, but did not succeed in finding the answer.

Answer (score 2):

To make it short its not possible as netty does use non-blocking IO while you want to use a ServerSocket which uses blocking IO.

Comment: is there any way to wrap around netty api to use it as blocking IO?

Comment: We have the OioSocketChannel that you may be able to use. That said I would not recommend it for high troughput stuff.